# Find a large subset of any $n$ integers where $a_1+2a_2=2a_3+2a_4$ is impossible.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> Let $B=\left\{ b_{1},...,b_{n}\right\} $ a set of distinct positive integers. Show that there exists a subset $A\subseteq B$, such that $|A|>\frac{1}{10} \cdot n$, and such that there does not exist $a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4 \in A$ such that $a_1+2a_2=2a_3+2a_4$. ($n 
> \geq 1$)

I have no clue where to start, I do have a few hints:
consider $p=4k+3$ and consider $(1/2,2/3]$, (specifically that  $3\cdot (1/2,2/3]\cap 4\cdot(1/2,2/3] = \emptyset$).
It should involve random variables and expectations, but I guess it is not the only way to solve, so any way would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think that this does not hold. Let $B=\{0\}$. The only subset $A$ with $|A|>1/10$ is $A=B$. But for $a_1=\dots=a_4=0$ we have $a_1+2a_2=0=2a_3+2a_4$.

Comment: @Matija I fixed it for positive integers. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is exercise 2.7.2 from the Probabilistic Method, Alon-Spencer, 4th edition. To solve it, mimic the proof of Theorem 1.4.1 in the same book. More specifically

> Take large prime $p$. Randomly choose an $x \in \mathbb{F}_p$, and take $B$ to be $\{a \in A: xa \in I\}$, where $I$ is an appropriate interval.